# Wrapping binary buffers - possible without extraneous moving/copying?

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, buffer, c++14

Fair warning, I am a C++ novice. So, some or all of my assumptions might be faulty.

Consider the following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class StaticData {
private:
    const T* data = nullptr;
    std::size_t size;
public:
    StaticData(const T* data, std::size_t size) : data(data), size(size) { }
    const T* GetData() {
        return this->data;
    }
    std::size_t GetSize() {
        return this->size;
    }
};

const unsigned char foo[] = { 0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F };
// Possible to initialize this class with data directly?
StaticData<unsigned char> SDFoo = StaticData<unsigned char>(foo, sizeof(foo));

int main() {
    std::printf("%p (%lu)\n", foo, sizeof(foo));
    std::printf("%p (%lu)\n", SDFoo.GetData(), SDFoo.GetSize());
}
```

With this code, I am wrapping `foo` in an (incomplete) class that contains the data and its value.  I have no interest in modifying the contained data, I simply want a safe wrapper for it that has its size always available.  I first tried `std::array`, but it has the unfortunate side effect of making the size a part of its type, and I cannot put arrays of different sizes inside a container such as an `std::unordered_map`.

The only problem with this approach is that `foo` is still hanging out in the global scope.  For safety's sake, I would much rather the container class `SDFoo` being the only thing visible (as `Foo` perhaps).  However, I can't figure out a way to get rid of `foo` without introducing unnecessary moving or copying of the entire buffer at static initialization time.

Any ideas?

EDIT: To be clear, I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the extra `foo` variable somehow.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to accomplish. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Barry The actual problem I am trying to solve is that I have a bunch of binary data for a bitmap font that I want to embed in my program (94 characters at 40-100 bytes each), and I wanted to see if there was a way to improve on the usual xxd C-style approach of barfing a byte array and its length to two different variables per binary blob. std::array looked nice and tidy on one line until I realized its length prevented use in containers.

Comment: So why not just `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2):

The only way (that I know of) to eliminate the `foo` variable from global memory is to allocate a copy of the data inside of the `StaticData` object itself.  You could use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (to allow you to make copies of `StaticData` without making extra copies of its data) and [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) to help you with that, eg:

```
#include <initializer_list> 
#include <memory> 

template <typename T>
class StaticData {
private:
    const T* m_data;
    std::size_t m_size;
    std::shared_ptr<T[]> m_storage;

public:
    StaticData(const T* data, std::size_t size)
        : m_data(data), m_size(size)
    {
    }

    StaticData(const std::initializer_list<T> &data)
        : m_storage(new T[data.size()]), m_data(m_storage.get()), m_size(data.size())
    {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), m_storage.get());
    }

    const T* GetData() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    std::size_t GetSize() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }
};

StaticData<unsigned char> SDFoo({ 0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F });

void bar(const char *str)
{
    StaticData<char> SDBar(str, strlen(str));
    std::printf("SDBar: %p (%lu)\n", SDBar.GetData(), SDBar.GetSize());
}

int main()
{
    std::printf("SDFoo: %p (%lu)\n", SDFoo.GetData(), SDFoo.GetSize());
    bar("baz");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you're looking for is a const view onto arbitrary data, where the data itself is private? Perhaps something like:

```
// foo.h
extern StaticData<const unsigned char> foo;
```

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
unsigned char foo_data[] = {0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef};
StaticData<const unsigned char> foo(foo_data, sizeof(foo_data));
```

This'll keep the actual data hidden, as it's only visible from the source file, and the only exported way to access it is through your const view.

Comment: This is what I was going to resort to if nothing else worked.  However, what I really wanted to know is if there was a way to get rid of the extra 'foo' variable somehow, period, without introducing unnecessary copying.

Comment: No. Think about it. How can you have a view into data that does not exist in memory?  At least you could declare `foo_data` as `static` (missing in the example above) so other units cannot access `foo_data` directly with an `extern`.  Otherwise, you would have to move the data directly into `StaticData`, such as with a `std::vector` if not a `std::array`.

Comment: You could give `StaticData` a constructor that accepts a `std::initialization_list` as input, then you can construct `foo` using `foo({0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef});`, but that doesn't solve the problem of making sure the source data remains valid for the lifetime of `foo`.  That is not what `std::initialization_list` is meant for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How can I have a view into data that does not exist in memory?  By getting a view of something that exists as part of a data segment.

For example, if I have a function `bar` that takes a const char* parameter, I can pass a string literal to it like `bar("baz")`, and take the address of that string literal.

Comment: That would still require using a named variable to initialize the view inside of `bar()`, eg: `void bar(const char *str) { StaticData<const char> foo(str, strlen(str)); ... }`

Comment: True, and that's okay.

I suppose what I was really hoping for was some nice way of doing `StaticData Foo({0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef})` all on one line without incurring the overhead of a copy/move, but it doesn't sound like I can do that.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` allows you to use that kind of syntax to initialize `Foo`, but the content of the list is not guaranteed to survive once the list goes out of scope after `Foo`'s constructor exits, so it is not safe to just grab a pointer to the list content, you have to copy it.